Migration from Spring Boot 2.2 to 3.2 - cannot find replacement for TypeDef and TypeDefs annotation from org.hibernate.annotations
I am migrating my Spring Boot application from Java 8 to Java 21 and Spring Boot 2.2 to 3.2. I am encountering problems related to deprecated hibernate annotations. I have an entity as follows
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "party_info")
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class) })
public class PartyInfo implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 48, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "update_on")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updateOn;

    @Column(name = "recorded_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date recordedAt;

    @Type(jsonb.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", name = "party", length = 500)
    private PartyResponse partyResponse;

}


The problem here is that TypeDefs and TypeDef cannot be found and jsonb.class also cannot be resolved. Is there any alternative way to solve this issue?

You could use @Convert to convert json into a pojo.
...
public class PartyInfo implements Serializable {
...
@Convert(converter = PartyAttributeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "party", length = 500)
private PartyResponse  party;

}

@Converter
public class PartyAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<PartyResponse, String> {
    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(PartyResponse address) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(address);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
            log.warn("Cannot convert PartyResponse into JSON");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PartyResponse convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(value, PartyResponse.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.warn("Cannot convert JSON into PartyResponse");
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Example how to use it can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jpa-storing-postgresql-jsonb

Can you give more information that is in the link. Links die or the information changes.

For JSON database column this annotation works for me:
    @JdbcTypeCode(org.hibernate.annotations.SqlTypes.JSON)
    private String cv;

